# Power BI performance

Tags: excel, database, powerbi, analytics, data-science

I need some help with improving power BI performance to read some data.
I currently import data from an excel sheet, a table with lots of different data types. And i was wondering if it is viable to change the data source, since it would have to be a one man job. 
Does power BI has better performance importing from another data source? Im considering access because of the simplicity of the change. Using a proper database like SQL is on the table but it wouldn't be as easy to do in a short time change.

Comment: Are you using Power BI Desktop or Power BI Service? Where is your Excel file (local folder, OneDrive, or anywhere else)? How much data volume does it have? Is there any kind of data transformation using PowerQuery? How long is it taking to refresh data? And what is the acceptable loading time for your use case?

Comment: `Dax Studio` could help here to analize your querys. Also outsourcing calculated columns into a measure. Maybe this link helps also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m34IOHcNPPo

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you using SQL SSAS. You can create all the metrics outside of PBI to after import only the summarized statistics going to the drill-down level you need for.